# iAd how to hide and show ads at a specifc point in my app

Tags: ios, iad

my goal is to have my iAd show at the main menu screen(which I already accomplished) but when the user push a button to start the game I want the ad to go away and when the game ends the ad to reappear...I saw a lot of other similar questions but none had answers(searched for hours :/ ). also checked the documentation and couldn't find a logical solution, I'm also a newbie,thanks!

*update the code im working with .h file

```
   -(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: First Request For `iAd` when you required and then you can animate it particular location.

Comment: [bannerView removeFromSuperview]; try this to remove and to add     [self.view addSubview: bannerView];

Comment: Unfortunately that suggestion didn't work for me. when i add the code i got an error, "fix it replace "bannerview" with "ADBannerView". once i "fix it" and replace bannerview with ADBanner view i get another error, "no known class method or selector removeFromSuperview"...any thoughts?  @mohitpopat

Comment: if possible can you show some code to clearly explain? @BuntyM

Comment: you got that error because may be you have not import the file in your particular view

Comment: imported the file? are you referring to the iAd framework? if so it is imported. @mohitpopat

Comment: ok put the code that you write to display add on main menu screen

Comment: bannerView i wrote was an object of ADBannerView

Comment: i updated the original post to better explain my problem. @mohitpopat